# Decrypt Ubuntu home from USB storage

Tags: 14.04, mount, encryption, ecryptfs

I will try to explain what happened step by step to be as clear as possible.

1. I messed up my /boot partition, rebooted and I couldn't make my Ubuntu 14.04 boot again.
2. I had HDD full encryption. Because of that, I couldn't repair my boot partition.
3. I have user home directory encryption.
4. I decrypted my user home dirrectory and backed up my files thought GUI copy/paste.
5. I copied the whole Ubuntu partition to an external hdd thought cp command and then I erased the whole disk (to delete hdd encryption).
6. I forgot to check "view hidden files" when I backed up my home directory so I didn't copy ".firefox" & ".thunderbird" folders which I CANNOT loose.
7. I copied the full hdd backup to the new partition and I tried to chroot my installation mounting /dev /proc & /sys from Ubuntu Live, but now it doesn't work.

I need help trying to decrypt again my home dir to backup .firefox & .thunderbird folders properly.

I only have the wrapped-password which is my user login password. I can also see the wrapped-passphrase file on `/home/user/.ecryptfs/user/.ecryptfs`/ so I should be able to recover the pass phrase from it, shouldn't I?

I'm currently using a Ubuntu 16.04 Live CD.

I ran this command:

```
sudo ecryptfs-recover-private /media/ubuntu/EXTERNALHDD/UBUNTU_BACKUP/home/user/
```

But it asks for the "MOUNT passphrase" which I don't know. How can I make it ask for the login password? Last time I backup my home directory, I chrooted my ubuntu installation so the ecryptfs asked me for the login password.

Any ideas?

Thanks.

Comment: Ok thx for the "fix".

Comment: Just an idea, so not really an "answer", but ecryptfs-recover-private is a bash script, you can view it quickly with `less $(which ecryptfs-recover-private)` and search for the "wrapped-passphrase" parts and maybe see why it's not using yours, maybe it's not in your backup?